# ECS Task definition by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

we have automated creation of fargate services and task definitions from our CI system.   Everything is named except task definitions, which just get a generated ID.    We tag them with the information we need, but can't find an easy way of finding a task definition by tag, beyond asking for the list of all task definitions and looping through, describing them and getting tags.

can any tell me if there's another way - basically putting something in a task definition at creation time that I can just say "find me *that* task definition" later?

Comment: Task revision number?

Comment: that's the point - that's the problem.  We have builds - builds get stamped with a version number from our ci system - this gets tagged into git- they get turned into a container, which has the same number - we have a lot that depends on it.  Trouble is, not every build gets deployed for various reasons, maybe as simple as something fails - so the task definition revision doesnt correspond.   we want to release version 3123 - we think in _our_ build numbers - and then have to find the corresponding task definition revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually - one of my co-workers figured it out - I told him to post here, but I guess he didn't.   You just do this:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region ${amazon_region} --resource-type-filters ecs:task-definition --tag-filters Key=*******,Values=***** Key=******,Values=******  --max-items 1 | jq --raw-output '.ResourceTagMappingList[].ResourceARN'
```

Comment: This is gold. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the party here, but I don't think it's possible to reference a task definition by tag (at least not after an hour pouring over the AWS documentation). For our CD setup we had to run a script that grabs all active task definitions and finds the one with a release tag value we want. It looks like this:

```
"""
Fetches a task definition based on family name and the `release` tag value.

Usage:
    python3 -m app.scripts.get_task_definition TASK_FAMILY RELEASE_TAG
"""

import sys

import boto3

task_family = sys.argv[1]
release = sys.argv[2]

ecs_client = boto3.client("ecs", region_name="us-west-2")

# Sort by newest first
list_response = ecs_client.list_task_definitions(familyPrefix=task_family, status="ACTIVE", sort="DESC")

for arn in list_response["taskDefinitionArns"]:
    task_definition = ecs_client.describe_task_definition(taskDefinition=arn, include=["TAGS"])
    task_release_tags = [tag for tag in task_definition["tags"] if "release" in tag["key"]]
    task_release = task_release_tags[0].get("value", None) if task_release_tags else None
    if task_release == release:
        print(arn)
```